# Group Data and Display in Accordion using AngularJs and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am NEW to MVC as well as AngularJs and have been toiling over this for days.  Although I feel that I am getting closer....still no cigar.

The problem:  I have a list of reports that are grouped on the report type(name).  I am trying to use an accordion to show and hide the list of reports in each group.

My controller.js looks like this (I know that it is wrong):

```
window.app.controller('relatedReportsController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'relatedReportsService',
function ($scope, $timeout, relatedReportService) {
    initialize();
    function initialize()
    {
        $scope.relatedReports = [];
        $scope.rollupVisible = false;
    }
    function sortOn(collection, name)
    {
        collection.sort(
            function (a, b) {
                if (a[name] <= b[name]) {
                    return (-1);
                }
                return (1);
            });
    }
    $scope.groupBy = function (attribute) {
        $scope.Groups = [];
        sortOn($scope.relatedReports, attribute);
        for (var i=0; i< $scope.relatedReports.length; i++)
        {
            var report = $scope.relatedReports[i];
        }
    }
    $scope.toggleRollup = function($event)
    {
        if (angular.element($event.targe).hasClass('glyph')) return;
        relatedReportService.$promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.relatedReports = data;
        })

    }
    }]);
```

My page looks like this:

```
                <li class="fruitRollup header row" ng-controller="relatedReportsController">
                <div class="suitcaseheader">
                    <span class="col-xs-10 zero firstlabel">{{group.Name}}</span>
                    <span class="col-xs-3 zero datepad">Date</span>
                    <span class="floatR2">View</span>
                    <span class="clear"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="eaten">
                     <ul class="data">
                        @*@foreach (var reportResult in resultGroup.OrderByDescending(r=>r.Date))
                        {*@
                            <li class="data row" ng-repeat="report in group.reports" ng-controller="relatedReportsController">
                                <div class="suitcase">
                                    <span class="col-xs-10 zero accountNumberColumn"></span>
                                    @*<span class="middle zero">@reportResult.Date.Replace("12:00:00","")</span>*@
                                    <span class="middle zero">{{report.Date}}</span>
                                    <span class="floatR2">
                                        <a class="icon-view glyph" target="_blank" href="@Url.ActionEncodedParameters("ViewDocument", "DocumentSearch", new { id = reportResult.Id })"></a>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="clear"></span>
                                </div>
```

As you can see I need a lot of help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seeing an error? Is it compiling successfully but you don't get the desired output? What exactly is the issue here? Have you looked to see if your controller is being called and if there is a javascript error happening somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The code that I had written in the controller.js was not properly getting the data.  In trying to use a combination of samples that I found on the internet, I was thoroughly confused.  I figured this out yesterday.  I didn't need to get the data through the controller.js because the data was already being fetched through my page controller.cs and viewmodel.  All I ended up needing was to use ng-show to show and hide the sections.

Thanks for taking the time to try to help.